# Is there a browser based front end for searching files on my server?

Tags: 12.04, server, lamp, search, smb

Searching on local clients over SMB is crazy slow and the users in the office will struggle with locate | grep. Is there a frontend I can run in the browser for my users to find files? I've had Sphinx suggested as a search tool but I don't have the know-how to implement it as a search for my users.